# Gradle build failure: Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':classpath'

Tags: gradle, build.gradle, gradle-eclipse

I have this error:

```
A problem occurred configuring root project <project-name>
Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':classpath'.
Could not resolve org.hibernate.build.gradle:version-injection-plugin:1.0.0.
Could not GET 'http:.../gradle/version-injection-plugin/1.0.0/version-injection-plugin-1.0.0.pom'. Received status code 401 from server: Unauthorized
Could not resolve org.tmatesoft.svnkit:svnkit:1.7.11.
Could not GET 'http:.../svnkit/1.7.11/svnkit-1.7.11.pom'. 
Received status code 401 from server: Unauthorized
```

Gradle version 3.6.3

Comment: Please add some details + build.gradle file.

Comment: The following line is mentioned in the build.gradle file..            dependencies {
classpath 'org.hibernate.build.gradle:version-injection-plugin:1.0.0'
classpath group: 'org.tmatesoft.svnkit', name: 'svnkit', version: '1.7.11'
 }.. Please let me know what kind of futher details you require

Comment: Please, edit you post and add build.gradle file as formatted part of code.

Comment: I cannot let out the build.gradle file. Please let me know whether the issue can be corrected with code changes in the build file or something is not correct with the settings in eclipse?

Comment: What do you want then if you can not post build.gradle file? I suppose there is not enough info to answer.

Comment: The code was working properly earlier. But, recently facing this build error. Please tell me what could be the reason for sudden Build Error

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Given that your getting an HTTP 401: Unauthorized, my gut says this is probably a `repository {}` declaration that you haven't declared credentials for.

Something like as described in the [Gradle User Guide](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_management.html)

```
repositories {
    maven {
        credentials {
            username 'user'
            password 'password'
        }
        url "http://repo.mycompany.com/maven2"
    }
}
```

Comment: I have included the mentioned lines. The code was working properly earlier. But, recently facing this build error. Please tell me what could be the reason for sudden Build Error

Comment: 401 means that wherever gradle is trying to download your dependency from, it is not allowed to. If your build worked before, maybe something has changed in your network environment and/or corporate maven repos. So maybe you have to find out what it is and if you need to add a password as Eric suggested.

Comment: Yep, as Kris suggested. Perhaps someone enabled authentication on a repository where there was none previously.

Comment: Thanks all. The issue is resolved. There was a change in the password. The application worked normally after giving the new password.

Comment: sometimes, in the `build.gradle`, people set a variable instead of a plaintext place to store this. that way, you can store your credentials in `~/.gradle/gradle.properties`, something like `mavenUser=someUser mavenPassword=somePassword` (replace space with an endline)

Comment: What should I enter for `username`?